# How can I transform TSQL WHILE EXIST to a more Set based approach?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't like how this TSQL turned out, specifically the use of WHILE EXISTS. Can I use set based operations instead to simplify it, instead of it looking like a cursor?

I've simplified the code as much as I could so it's readable i.e. removing some table names and inserts. I've tried to use a Map but couldn't get it to work. Could you kindly point me in the right direction?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM /**SomeTable**/ WHERE [code] = 'EQUIPMENT') OR      EXISTS(SELECT * FROM /**Some Other Table**/ WHERE [code] = 'EQUIPMENT') 
BEGIN

/** INSERT NEW DATA **/

SELECT [equipmentTypeId] INTO #TempTable FROM [equipment].[EquipmentType]

DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @layoutCode NVARCHAR(80)
DECLARE @lastInsertedLayoutDefinitionId BIGINT
DECLARE @lastInsertedGridViewDefinitionId BIGINT    
DECLARE @lastInsertedGroupDefinitionId BIGINT

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TempTable)
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 1 @ID = [equipmentTypeId]
   FROM #TempTable

   SET @layoutCode = 'Test'

   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//
   SET @lastInsertedLayoutDefinitionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//
   set @lastInsertedGridViewDefinitionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//
   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//
   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//

   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//
   SET @lastInsertedGroupDefinitionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//
   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//
   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//
   INSERT INTO /**Some Table**// VALUES /** Some values *//

   DELETE #TempTable
   WHERE equipmentTypeId = @ID
END
DROP TABLE #TempTable
END
```

Comment: have you tried using INSERT INTO...SELECT....? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: In your case you are doing it this way to capture the `IDENTITY` value and use in the next step. i.e. load a lookup table and use the lookup key to populate a transactional table. The only way to do this in a set based fashion is to preserve the original unique key from the source table in both the lookup table and the transactional table, then use those keys in a single update to transfer the new identity value across. Does `[equipment].[EquipmentType]` have a unique key? Is it being saved into all of the tables?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid [equipment].[EquipmentType] is a foreign key, so yes

Comment: I'm assuming you are using those bigint id's in inserts?

Comment: I think you mean `[equipment].[EquipmentType]` is a table that is part of a foreign key. Is the column value in `equipmentTypeId` being inserted into the new lookup table? (i.e. the first inserted table that generated the identity value). Is it being inserted into the new transaction table (i.e. the last inserted table that uses `@lastInsertedLayoutDefinitionId` )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you are wanting to capture the inserted ID so that you can then insert it as a foreign-key reference in child tables.

Previously I used another approach which is also described here.
http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2012/06/12/merge-gives-better-output-options/

Here is a simplified version of my script:

```
CREATE TABLE #ActivityIDMappingTable (
    OldActivityID int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    NewActivityID int);

WITH Source As (
    SELECT ActivityID, ActivityCode, ActivityName, ...
      FROM #IncomingActivities)
MERGE INTO dbo.Activity AS Target
USING Source ON 1 = 0

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
  THEN INSERT (ActivityCode, ActivityName, ...)
  VALUES (Source.ActivityCode, Source.ActivityName, ...)

OUTPUT Source.ActivityID, Inserted.ActivityID
  INTO #ActivityIDMappingTable (OldActivityID, NewActivityID);


INSERT INTO dbo.Milestone (MilestoneCode, MilestoneName, ActivityID, ...)
SELECT MilestoneCode, MilestoneName, 
    ActivityID = New.ActivityID
  FROM #IncomingMilestones As m
  JOIN #ActivityIDMappingTable As a On m.ActivityID = a.OldActivityID;
```

Using the`MERGE` statement in this way will insert all rows from the source table (so I used a join predicate which will always be false). The key is that the `OUTPUT` clause can output something both from the source and target tables, which you want in order to maintain that linkage between the rows in various tables.

Obviously you will need to tailor to your table structure, but this can eliminate the loop and should perform much better.